# How do I fix this Django in azure deployment error “Exception Type: OperationalError Exception Value: no such table?"

Tags: python, django, azure

I have this Django app running on my computer, as a local server and I deployed it to an azure server. It works fine locally however when it runs on the azure server gives me this error.

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://runnify.azurewebsites.net/route/
Django Version: 3.0.5
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: pages_routerequest
Exception Location: /antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 396
Python Executable:  /opt/python/3.7.7/bin/python3.7
Python Version: 3.7.7
Python Path:    
['/opt/python/3.7.7/bin',
 '/home/site/wwwroot',
 '/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/opt/python/3.7.7/lib/python37.zip',
 '/opt/python/3.7.7/lib/python3.7',
 '/opt/python/3.7.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/opt/python/3.7.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 7 Sep 2020 11:21:54 +0000
```

I can't understand what is wrong, since I am not using a pages_routerequest anywhere.
in my models.py I have:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class Coordinates(models.Model):
    """Model representing a route coordinate generated (e.g. Science Fiction, Non Fiction)."""
    coordinates = JSONField()

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Coordinates objects"""
        return self.coordinates

class RouteRequest(models.Model):
    running_distance = models.FloatField()
    user_location = models.CharField(max_length=8000)
```

EDIT:
I have also applied makemigrations and migrate, and the bd was successfully created.

FIX:
I was required to have a database in azure directly and I didn't know. For now just took the .save() part out and it worked

Comment: have you applied the database migration?

Comment: I did, makemigrations and migrate

Answer (score 0):

You should commit migrations on production server

```sh
python3 manage.py makemigrations  # Optional if you control migrations on dev
python3 manage.py migrate
```

Comment: on Azure directly?

Comment: Yep, you are using sqlite, so you have no database file.

Comment: I think Azure uses containers without volumes, so you may lose all data on next deployment, you can think about migrating your project to server based dbms (like PostgreSQL). Azure exactly provides it.

Answer (score 0):

From first impression it seems you have missed to create them "db":

```
    python manage.py migrate
    python manage.py makemigrations REPLACE-WITH-YOUR-PROJECT-NAME-HERE
    python manage.py migrate
```